# How to catch Google Video Intelligence DeadlineExceeded exception?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm iterating a big list of videos and running each one through Google Video Intelligence. It works fine for most videos, but if a video returns an exception, the code (Python 3.x) should skip it without stopping the iteration (added some code to write the name of the video which originated the error to a CSV file to check later).

I used the try/except routine, but even if I do not call a specific exception, which should catch any, it breaks the iteration.

This is the code:

```
from google.cloud import videointelligence
from google.api_core.exceptions import *

(...)

operation = video_client.annotate_video(input_content=input_content, 
                                        features=features, 
                                        video_context=context,
                                        retry=None)
try:
    result = operation.result(timeout=600)
except:
    result = False
    pass
```

This is the exception raised:

```
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 549, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 466, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
    details = "Deadline Exceeded"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1556638076.747183038","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1039,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "annotate_videos.py", line 153, in <module>
    main()
  File "annotate_videos.py", line 149, in main
    process_videos(videos)
  File "annotate_videos.py", line 127, in process_videos
    result = annotate_videos_alternative(fallback_url)
  File "annotate_videos.py", line 59, in annotate_videos_alternative
    retry=None)
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/videointelligence_v1/gapic/video_intelligence_service_client.py", line 282, in annotate_video
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bernardo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.DeadlineExceeded: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, it seems the exception is coming from the line

```
operation = video_client.annotate_video(input_content=input_content, 
                                        features=features, 
                                        video_context=context,
                                        retry=None)
```

Try moving your `try` statement a line up.